# Error while making the com activex dll in visual basic 6.0

Tags: vb.net, com, components, activex

while creating the Com dll - Activex dll in Microsoft Visual basic 6.0, i got the following error - "Error accessing the system registry". Can you please provide your input on this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't have administrative credentials when performing this action.